# EXTREMELY Confused Over "Constant Game Speed Maximum FPS" Game Loop

Tags: architecture, game-loop

I recently read this article on Game Loops: http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/

And the recommended last implementation is confusing me deeply. I don't understand how it works, and it looks like a complete mess.

I understand the principle: Update the game at a constant speed, with whatever is left render the game as many times as possible.

I take it you cannot use a:

- Get input for 25 ticks
- Render game for 975 ticks

Approach since you would be getting input for the first portion of the second and this would feel weird? Or is that what is going on in the article?

---

**Essentially:**

```
while( GetTickCount() > next_game_tick && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP)
```

How is that even valid?

Let's assume his values.

```
MAX_FRAMESKIP = 5
```

Let's assume next_game_tick, which was assigned moments after initialization, before the main game loop is say... 500.

Finally, as I am using SDL and OpenGL for my game, with OpenGL being used for rendering only, let's assume that `GetTickCount()` returns the time since SDL_Init was called, which it does.

```
SDL_GetTicks -- Get the number of milliseconds since the SDL library initialization.
```

*Source: http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlgetticks.html*

The author also assumes this:

```
DWORD next_game_tick = GetTickCount();
// GetTickCount() returns the current number of milliseconds
// that have elapsed since the system was started
```

**If we expand the `while` statement we get:**

```
while( ( 750 > 500 ) && ( 0 < 5 ) )
```

750 because time has passed since `next_game_tick` was assigned. `loops` is zero as you can see in the article.

So we have entered the while loop, let's do some logic and accept some input.

Yadayadayada.

**At the end of the while loop, which I remind you is inside our main game loop is:**

```
next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
loops++;
```

Let's update what the next iteration of the while code looks like

```
while( ( 1000 > 540 ) && ( 1 < 5 ) )
```

**1000** because time has elapsed getting input and doing stuff before we reached the next ineteration of the loop, where GetTickCount() is recalled.

**540** because, in the code 1000 / 25 = 40, therefore, 500 + 40 = 540

**1** because our loop has iterated once

**5**, you know why.

---

So, since this While loop is CLEARLY depedent on `MAX_FRAMESKIP` and not the intended `TICKS_PER_SECOND = 25;` how is the game supposed to even run correctly?

It was no surprise to me that when I implemented this into my code, correctly I might add as I simply renamed my functions to handle user input and draw the game to what the author of the article has in his example code, the game did nothing.

I placed an `fprintf( stderr, "Test\n" );` inside the while loop which doesn't get printed until the game ends.

**How is this game loop running 25 times a second, guaranteed, while rendering as fast as it can?**

To me, unless I am missing something HUGE, it looks like... nothing.

And isn't this structure, of this while loop, supposedly running 25 times a second and then updating the game exactly what I mentioned beforehand at the start of the article?

If that is the case why couldn't we do something simple like:

```
while( loops < 25 )
{
    getInput();
    performLogic();

    loops++;
}

drawGame();
```

And count for interpolation some other way.

Forgive my extremely long question, but this article has done more harm than good to me. I am severely confused now - and have no idea how to implement a proper game loop because of all these arisen questions.

Comment: Rants are better directed toward the article's author. Which part is your *objective question*?

Comment: Is this game loop even valid, someone explain. From my tests it doesn't have the correct structure to run 25 times a second. Explain to my why it does. Also this isn't a rant, this is a series of questions. Must I use emoticons, do I seem angry?

Comment: Since your question boils down to "What am I not understanding about this game loop", and you have lots of bold-font words, it comes off as at least exasperated.

Comment: @Kirbinator I can appreciate that, but I was trying to ground all that I find unusual in this article so it isn't a shallow and empty question. I don't think it is quintessential that anyway, I'd like to think I have some valid points - after all that is an article trying to teach, but not doing such a good job.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it's a good question, it just could be 80% shorter.

Comment: @Kirbinator I'll concede to that haha.

Comment: @tsujp for a game to run at 60fps, its update + draw cycles MUST run at a combined total of ~16ms. So if your update cycle is taking ~6ms and each iteration through the while loop is adding 40ms to the `next_tick`...  The `max_skip` is there in the case where something HAS farted and the timing is way behind. See my response for more.

Answer (score 9):

I think the author made a tiny error:

`while( GetTickCount() > next_game_tick && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP)`

should be

`while( GetTickCount() < next_game_tick && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP)`

That is: as long as it is not yet time to draw our next frame and while we have not skipped as much frames as MAX_FRAMESKIP  we should wait.

I also don't understand why he updates `next_game_tick` in the loop and I assume it is another error. Since at the start of a frame you can determine when the next frame should be (when using a fixed frame rate). The `next game tick` does not depend on how much time we have left over after updating and rendering.

The author also makes another common error

> with whatever is left render the game as many times as possible.

This means rendering the same frame multiple times. The author is even aware of that:

> The game will be updated at a steady 50 times per second, and rendering
>   is done as fast as possible. Remark that when rendering is done more
>   than 50 times per second, some subsequent frames will be the same, so
>   actual visual frames will be displayed at a maximum of 50 frames per
>   second.

This only causes the GPU to do unnecessary work and if rendering takes longer than expected it could cause you to start working on your next frame later than intended so it is better to yield to the OS and wait.

Comment: +Vote. Mmmm. This indeed leaves me puzzled on what to do then. I thank you for your insight. I shall probably have a play around, the problem is really knowledge on limiting FPS or having FPS dynamically set, and how to do that. In my mind fixed input handling is **required** so the game runs at the same pace for everyone. This is only a simple 2D Platformer MMO (in the very long run)

Comment: While loop seems correct and incrementing next_game_tick is there for that. It is there to keep simulation running at constant speed on slower and faster hardware. Running the rendering code "as fast as possible" (or faster than physics anyway) makes sense only when there is interpolation in rendering code to make it more smooth for fast objects etc (end of the article), but that is just wasted energy if it is rendering more than what whatever output device (screen) is able to show.

Comment: So his code is a valid implementation, now that is. And we just have to live with this waste? Or are there methods I can look up for this.

Comment: Yielding to the OS and waiting is only a good idea if you have a good idea of when the OS will return control to you - which may not be as soon as you'd like.

Comment: I can't vote this answer up. He's completely missing the interpolation stuff, which rather makes the entire second half of the answer invalid.

Comment: @Dotti, yes but incrementing the next_game_tick during waiting is wrong (I think, or at least I can't see why the author would want that) you should be able to say at the beginning of your frame when the next frame should start in order to keep a constant framerate.

Comment: @Kylotan I thought it was better to busy-wait too, but then someone showed me the Quake 3 source code, which yields (sleep(0)) instead of busy waits.

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir I skimmed the original article and there they don't talk about interpolation, that of course would be a valid reason for drawing more often than updating. But even then it is a questionable practice. If you update at a fixed 60fps but render and interpolate at 120fps you can interpolate 2 frames per update, I don't think that is going to be visible. And at frame rates not exact multiples of your target frame rate you get into a lot of trouble. Some updates you will interpolate 2 or 3 times and some only one, this might cause stuttering (if you can see that fast).

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir I think interpolating is only useful when running multiplayer (strategy) games where you run in lockstep at a lot lower FPS (like 15) so the interpolation is need to reduce choppiness and actually visible. But the article talks about a target frame rate of 50FPS.

Comment: This is incorrect, the correct code was indeed the > next_game_tick. Well, technically it should be >=. Basically, if the current time is >= the next time you want to do logic (physics, AI, input, etc.) and you have done this logic step 4 times or less, then do logic. Otherwise, just render.

You are only incorrect because you missunderstood the point of next_game_tick, it is not when you render the next frame, it is when you do logical events.

Comment: This answer is not correct, it has misunderstood the use of this comparison: GetTickCount() > next_game_tick

Answer (score 4):

Maybe best if I simplify it a bit:

```
while( game_is_running ) {

    current = GetTickCount();
    while(current > next_game_tick) {
        update_game();

        next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
    }
    display_game();
}
```

`while` loop inside mainloop is used to run simulation steps from where ever it was, to where it should be now. `update_game()` function should always assume that only `SKIP_TICKS` amount of time has passed since last call. This will keep game physics running at constant speed on slow and fast hardware.

Incrementing `next_game_tick` by amount of `SKIP_TICKS` moves it closer to current time. When this gets bigger than current time is, it breaks (`current > next_game_tick`) and mainloop continues to render current frame.

After rendering, next call to `GetTickCount()` would return new current time. If this time is higher than `next_game_tick` it means that we are already behind 1-N steps in simulation and we should catch up, running every step in simulation at same constant speed. In this case if it is lower, it would just render same frame again (unless there is interpolation).

Original code had limited the number of loops if we are left too far away (`MAX_FRAMESKIP`). This only makes it actually show something and not looking like being locked up if for example resuming from suspend or game being paused in debugger for long time (assuming `GetTickCount()` does not stop during that time) until it has catched up with time.

To get rid of useless same frame rendering if you are not using interpolation inside `display_game()`, you could wrap it inside if statement like:

```
while (game_is_running) {
    current = GetTickCount();
    if (current > next_game_tick) {
        while(current > next_game_tick) {
            update_game();

            next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
        }
    display_game();
    }
    else {
    // could even sleep here
    }
}
```

This is also a good article about this: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Also, maybe reason why your `fprintf` outputs when your game ends might just be that it did not get flushed.

Sorry about my english.

Answer (score 4):

His code looks entirely valid.

Consider the `while` loop of the last set:

```
// JS / pseudocode
var current_time = function () { return Date.now(); }, // in ms
    framerate = 1000/30, // 30fps
    next_frame = current_time(),

    max_updates_per_draw = 5,

    iterations;

while (game_running) {

    iterations = 0;

    while (current_time() > next_frame && iterations < max_updates_per_draw) {
        update_game(); // input, physics, audio, etc

        next_frame += framerate;
        iterations += 1;
    }

    draw();
}
```

I've got a system in place which says
"while the game is running, check the current time - if it's greater than our running framerate tally, and we've skipped drawing fewer than 5 frames, then skip drawing and just update input and physics: else draw the scene and start the next update iteration"

When each update happens, you increment the "next_frame" time by your ideal framerate.
Then you check your time again.  If your current time is now less than when the next_frame should be updated, then you skip over the update and draw what you've got.

If your current_time is greater (imagine that the last draw process took a really long time, because there was some hiccup somewhere, or a bunch of garbage-collection in a managed language, or a managed-memory implementation in C++ or whatever), then draw gets skipped and the `next_frame` gets updated with *another* extra frame worth of time, until either the updates catch up to where we should be on the clock, or we've skipped drawing enough frames that we absolutely MUST draw one, so the player can see what they're doing.

If your machine is super-fast or your game is super-simple, then `current_time` might be less than `next_frame` frequently, which means that you are not updating during those points.

That's where the interpolation comes in.
Likewise, you could have a separate bool, declared outside of the loops, to declare "dirty" space.

Inside of the update loop, you'd set `dirty = true`, signifying that you've actually performed an update.

Then, instead of just calling `draw()`, you'd say:

```
if (is_dirty) {
    draw(); 
    is_dirty = false;
}
```

Then you're missing out on any interpolation for smooth motion, but you're ensuring that you're only updating when you've got updates actually happening (rather than interpolations between states).

If you're brave, there's an article called "Fix Your Timestep!" by GafferOnGames.
It approaches the problem slightly differently, but I consider it a prettier solution which does mostly the same thing (depending on your language's features, and how much you care about your game's physics calculations).